# Opensearch scoring script with bool filter java

Tags: java, elasticsearch, knn, opensearch, scoring

I have the following example from Opensearch documentation

```
InlineScript inlineScript = new InlineScript.Builder()
        .source("knn_score")
        .lang("knn")
        .params(Map.of(
                "field", JsonData.of("my_vector"),
                "query_value", JsonData.of(List.of(1.5, 5.5, 4.5, 6.4)),
                "space_type", JsonData.of("cosinesimil")
                ))
        .build();
Query query = new Query.Builder()
        .scriptScore(new ScriptScoreQuery.Builder()
            .query(new Query.Builder()
                .matchAll(new MatchAllQuery.Builder().build())
                .build())
            .script(new Script.Builder()
                .inline(inlineScript)
                .build())
            .build())
        .build();
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest.Builder()
        .index(index)
        .query(query)
        .build();
SearchResponse<JsonNode> searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest, JsonNode.class);
```

I would like to do something similar, but instead of a matchAll query, I would like to use a BoolQuery. This is a sample BoolQuery:

```
      BoolQueryBuilder boolQuery = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();

      BoolQueryBuilder innerBoolQuery = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();

      innerBoolQuery.must(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("price").gte(200).lte(350));

      boolQuery.filter(innerBoolQuery);
```

I want to do something like this, but have been unsuccessful:

```
Query query = new Query.Builder()
        .scriptScore(new ScriptScoreQuery.Builder()
            .query(boolQuery) ---> Compilation error.
            .script(new Script.Builder()
                .inline(inlineScript)
                .build())
            .build())
        .build();
```

An example of how I want my actual query to look like:

```
GET /my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "script_score": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "range": {
                    "price": {
                      "gte": 200,
                      "lte": 350
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "script": {
        "source": "knn_score",
        "lang": "knn",
        "params": {
          "field": "my_vector",
          "query_value": [1.5, 5.5, 4.5, 6.4],
          "space_type": "cosinesimil"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am using the opensearch-java client. Kindly help.

Comment: If you have already made query in dev tool, why don't you make it search-template, and invoke that particular search-template in Java client.

Comment: Because I have multiple filters in my bool query and they will change depending on the input. It'd be cleaner if I do it programmatically.

Comment: Multiple filters can be configured in search-template, actually it's quite easy if you do some study, and also most used approach because you can use that template also in dev tool not only in Java client. And in fact, sometimes in Java client it gets so complicated because of Strings.

Comment: Do you have a link for the search-template?

Comment: Sure, [following shows how to make search template in dev tool](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-template.html), and [this github repo](https://github.com/af4092/Elasticsearch-Search-Template-Invoking-Java-Client) shows how to invoke search template. Additionally [you can build](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-template.html) search template directly in the Java client as well. But personally I would recommend to build them in dev tool, because in this way you can use them both in the elastic query and java client